# GROUP BY for SELECT one column

Tags: sql, select, group-by, database

If I am selecting one column, something like

```
SELECT columnname FROM table
```

will the result always be in the same order as

```
SELECT columnname FROM table GROUP BY columnname
```

or does it depend on the DB management system?

Comment: They will probably be the same order, but it is not guaranteed.  If the order matters, always use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it would *not* be the same, because the first query may return duplicates, while the second query wouldn't.

This query, on the other hand, will return the same results as the `group by` one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnname FROM table
```

The order of the results may be different.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the same, if you grup oyu will get only one record per columnname, the other you can have more than one.

Answer (score 1):

The order is not defined by any of the queries you posted...
To set the order you must put the ORDER BY clause, like this:

```
    SELECT columnname FROM table ORDER BY columnname;
```

The result may come into duplicated rows or not... it depends if you have duplicated values on your table. The GROUP BY clause will only select one of each kind, which could be set as it follows:

```
    SELECT columnname FROM table GROUP BY columnname ORDER BY columnname;
```

Or, as Dasblink said earlier, using DISTINCT clause...

```
    SELECT DISTINCT columnname FROM table ORDER BY columnname;
```

Note that you may use only ORDER BY and the argumment or put a ASC or DESC condition, so the order will come from the higher to lower value.